# My proof is wrong, can anyone tell me why?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logic, proof-verification

$$\forall x \in \mathbb{Z}, \forall y \in \mathbb{Z}, [x(x+1) = y(y+1)] \Leftrightarrow [x = y]$$
$$\forall x \in \mathbb{Z} , \forall y \in \mathbb{Z}, [x(x+1)=y(y+1)]\Leftrightarrow [x=y]$$
$$\forall x \in \mathbb{Z} , \forall y \in \mathbb{Z}, [x^{2}+x=y^{2}+y)]\Leftrightarrow [0=x-y]$$
$$\forall x \in \mathbb{Z} , \forall y \in \mathbb{Z}, [x-y=y^{2}-x^{2})]\Leftrightarrow [0=x-y]$$
$$\forall x \in \mathbb{Z} , \forall y \in \mathbb{Z}, [y^{2}-x^{2}=0]\Leftrightarrow [0=x-y]$$
$$\forall x \in \mathbb{Z} , \forall y \in \mathbb{Z}, [x^{2}=y^{2}]\Leftrightarrow [0=x-y]$$
$$\forall x \in \mathbb{Z} , \forall y \in \mathbb{Z}, [x=y]\Leftrightarrow [x=y]$$

The statement is untrue, but I can't seem to prove it, any ideas?

Comment: I plugged in 0 for x-y on the left side because 0=x-y on the right side

Comment: $$\forall x \in \mathbb{Z} , \forall y \in \mathbb{Z}, [x-y=y^{2}-x^{2})]\Leftrightarrow [0=x-y]$$
$$\forall x \in \mathbb{Z} , \forall y \in \mathbb{Z}, [y^{2}-x^{2}=0]\Leftrightarrow [0=x-y]$$ These statements aren't equivalent.

Comment: Let $x=0$ and $y=-1$. Many other counterexamples. We need restrictions if the statement is to hold.

Comment: Doesn't x=y make a restriction?

Comment: Oliver: I believe what @André is trying to say is that we must restrict *which* pairs of integers we're looking at. In particular, we need to look at $x,y\in\Bbb Z$ such that $x+y\neq-1.$ Given that restriction, we *will* have $x(x+1)=y(y+1)$ if and only if $x=y.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Knowing only that $x^2=y^2$ isn't enough to conclude that $x=y,$ so you can't draw your final conclusion.

Rather, the following are equivalent among integers $x,y$: $$x^2=y^2$$ $$x^2-y^2=0$$ $$(x+y)(x-y)=0$$ $$x+y=0\text{ or }x-y=0$$ $$x=-y\text{ or }x=y$$

Furthermore, you cannot get from the statement $$\forall x\in\Bbb Z,\forall y\in\Bbb Z[x-y=y^2-x^2]\iff[0=x-y]$$ to the statement $$\forall x\in\Bbb Z,\forall y\in\Bbb Z[y^2-x^2=0]\iff[x-y=0]$$ by "substitution" in the way that you have. In particular, observe that the former statement is false when $x=0$ and $y=-1,$ while the latter is true! In order for statements of this sort to be equivalent (and not merely share a truth value), they must agree for all instances of the relevant variables.

---

**Added**: As a side note, the following are equivalent among integers $x,y$: $$x(x+1)=y(y+1)$$ $$x^2+x=y^2+y$$ $$x-y=y^2-x^2$$ $$x-y=(x+y)(y-x)$$ $$x-y=-(x+y)(x-y)$$ $$(x+y)(x-y)+x-y=0$$ $$(x+y+1)(x-y)=0$$ $$x+y+1=0\text{ or }x-y=0$$ $$x=-y-1\text{ or }x=y$$

Comment: So if 
   $$x^2-y^2=(x+y)(x-y)$$ $$(x+y)(x-y)!=(x-y)$$
Does that disprove it?

Comment: If you want to disprove a universal statement, then all you have to do is find one counterexample. If you wish to disprove the universal statement $$\forall x\in\Bbb Z,\forall y\in\Bbb Z,[x^2-y^2=0]\iff[x-y=0],$$ for example, then you need to find some $x,y\in\Bbb Z$ for which the biconditional $$[x^2-y^2=0]\iff[x-y=0]$$ does not hold. One of the conditionals will always hold, so you'd need to find $x,y\in\Bbb Z$ such that $x^2-y^2=0$ and $x-y\neq0.$